# Count Monthly Visitor based on their Purpose

Tags: mysql, count

Hi everybody,
I have this visitors table:

```
ID | Date | Purpose
1 | 20/10/2016 | Purpose1
2 | 22/10/2016 | Purpose1
3 | 25/10/2016 | Purpose2
4 | 12/11/2016 | Purpose1
5 | 14/11/2016 | Purpose2
6 | 16/11/2016 | Purpose2
```

Currently I'm using this query:

```
select case
            when date like '%/10/2016' then '10/2016'
            when date like '%/11/2016' then '11/2016'
        end as month, count(*) as total 
        from visitors 
        where 
            date like '%/10/2016' 
            or date like '%/11/2016' 
        GROUP by month
```

I can only get month and total column count from query above. How can I achieve this output?

```
Month | Total | Purpose1 | Purpose2
10/2016 | 3 | 2 | 1
11/2016 | 3 | 1 | 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Store dates using a date data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,Date DATE NOT NULL
,Purpose VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2016-10-20','Purpose1'),
(2,'2016-10-22','Purpose1'),
(3,'2016-10-25','Purpose2'),
(4,'2016-11-12','Purpose1'),
(5,'2016-11-14','Purpose2'),
(6,'2016-11-16','Purpose2');

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') month
     , SUM(purpose = 'purpose1') purpose1
     , SUM(purpose = 'purpose2') purpose2
     , COUNT(*) total 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY month;
+---------+----------+----------+-------+
| month   | purpose1 | purpose2 | total |
+---------+----------+----------+-------+
| 2016-10 |        2 |        1 |     3 |
| 2016-11 |        1 |        2 |     3 |
+---------+----------+----------+-------+
```

..or (and in my view, better, provided you have access to application code)...

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') month
     , purpose
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM my_table
 GROUP 
    BY month
     , purpose;

+---------+----------+-------+
| month   | purpose  | total |
+---------+----------+-------+
| 2016-10 | Purpose1 |     2 |
| 2016-10 | Purpose2 |     1 |
| 2016-11 | Purpose1 |     1 |
| 2016-11 | Purpose2 |     2 |
+---------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Transposing tables isn't very fast. It is better to do so in some small program.

If you do a

```
select case
            when date like '%/10/2016' then '10/2016'
            when date like '%/11/2016' then '11/2016'
        end as month, count(*) as total, Purpose 
        from visitors 
        where 
            date like '%/10/2016' 
            or date like '%/11/2016' 
        GROUP by month, Purpose
```

You'll have a good starting point.
You might need to add an ORDER BY clause (depending on your DBMS).

If (and only if) you only have two purposes in your table and the table isn't huge in size, you can create two views and join them.

Comment: Transposing tables might not be fast. Queries which cannot use indexes are definitely slow.

Comment: No discussion about that. But if you want to transpose the table and happen to have 50 purposes, you're going to need quite a lot of joins. This will increase the penalty of not being able to use an index by a factor of 50.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, currently I have only three purposes

Comment: In a well-indexed environment, lots of JOINs shouldn't prove too much of a problem. However, for different reasons, I agree with you that the transposition is best done in application code.